# How can I make resolving git merge conflicts easier on command line

Tags: git, git-merge

I like to resolve merge conflicts on the command line, because that way I know exactly what I am doing. This is great for pretty simple merges, but if things get messy, it takes a long time. Are there any command line tools are techniques that would help?

Comment: Hm.  I need a little more detail:  what exactly are you doing now, and how is it suboptimal?

Comment: If you have lots of conflicts, you might just have waited too long with merging.

Comment: Right now, I open up each file in vim and manually make the changes. Its fine for small conflicts and it makes me feel confident I did the merge right. 99% of the time this suits my needs, but today I have to do a big messy merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following in `.gitconfig`

```
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3

[mergetool]
    prompt = 1
```

If I now perform a merge with `git mergetool`, then it'll use kdiff3 which is much better for complicated merges.
Of course, you can adjust the mergetool to your liking, see [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/fix-merge-conflicts-in-git?rq=1)